# Open Sources Calculus Textbook Recommendations

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I will be instructing Calculus 1 at the local Junior College come fall. I have been given free range to use what ever text I would like.

I am looking for recommendations for an open sources calculus textbook. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For an introductory calculus class, I really like this set of notes: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/calci.aspx. It is clear, has good explanations with examples, and has a lot of solid practice questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this open source site very helpful:

https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus